# Stream video from one iphone to another and back

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to develop an conference application. It's basically exact the same as Facetime only with some extra features.

But how do I make a video chat from one iPhone to another iPhone LIVE like Facetime?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OpenTok is a good way to do it.

Here's [the tutorial](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/tools/as3/tutorials/switching.html)

You can use the flash builder or just air sdk